# Azure Media Services v3 shared access policy for download link

Tags: c#, .net, azure, video-processing, azure-media-services

How to secure download links created via Azure Media Services transformation job (and locator)?

I'm aware of using [AES](https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/azure/media-services/latest/protect-with-aes128) or [DRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/azure/media-services/latest/protect-with-drm) encryption for video **streams** created by Azure Media Services, however, I haven't found any info on how to secure **download** links.

I'm getting my download paths for my streaming locator like:

```
var locator = new StreamingLocator { AssetName = assetName, StreamingPolicyName = PredefinedStreamingPolicy.DownloadAndClearStreaming };
ListPathsResponse paths = await client.StreamingLocators.ListPathsAsync(config.ResourceGroup, config.AccountName, locatorName);
```

And then creating download links like:

```
foreach (var path in paths.DownloadPaths)
{
  UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
  uriBuilder.Scheme = "https";
  uriBuilder.Host = streamingEndpoint.HostName;

  uriBuilder.Path = path;
  downloadUrls.Add(uriBuilder.ToString());
}
```

I assume I should pass a specific policy when creating a locator, nevertheless, I was not able to find any relevant resources to achieve such behavior.

I've found many pieces of information about [legacy v2's sas URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-portal-vod-get-started#publish-content) and [access policies for REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/accesspolicy) but no luck with v3 and .net.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Media Services v3 API you should actually use the Storage APIs to create SAS URLs.  You can use the Asset.container (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/assets/createorupdate#definitions) to get the Storage container name that is associated with the asset.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for the recommendation. This was my intention at first, nevertheless, I thought it is an antipattern and one should get links directly from Media Service API (according to this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/storage-account-concept#assets-in-a-storage-account).